# How to set concatenated string variable in Ansible template based on a condition

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I need to create a string in a template that can change between hosts, and it needs to be in the form of:
"cores": "0,1,2,3"

And the reason the string is "0,1,2,3" in this example is because the host has 4 processor cores.

So I got stuck with something which seems too convoluted to me and I'm not even sure how to use this core_count variable in my template file.

```
{% set core_count = '' %}
{% for i in range(ansible_processor_cores) %}
  {% set core_count = core_count ~ i %}
    {% if not loop.last %}
     {% set core_count = core_count ~ ',' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many handy [lookup](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html) plugins in Ansible. Take `sequence`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: '"cores": "{{ lookup("sequence","start=0 count="+(ansible_processor_cores|string)) }}"'
```